# Ruby can an instance variable be printed instead of the instance address?

Tags: arrays, ruby, class, instance, instance-variables

I was recently experimenting in ruby and came across a snag. I want to push a class instance to an array and instead of it output this when the array elements are printed:
[#< WeaponItem:0x00000002a28058 @wName="M16A1", @mP=5, @mxP=35 >]

I instead want it to output:

> ["M16A1"]

but symbols and instance variables (self.variable, self.class.variable) don't have the intended effect and I can't hammer just the right method so I was wondering if this is even a possible endeavor.

Code:

```
class WeaponItem  
  attr_reader :wName  
  def initialize(wName,mPower,mxPower)    
    @wName = wName
    @mP = mPower
    @mxP = mxPower
  end

  def getStats
    puts "Weapon"
    puts "Name: #{@wName}"
    puts "Damage: #{@mP}~#{@mxP}"
  end

  def calculateDamage()
    rMAX = @mxP/@mP
    rMAX
  end  
end

vA = Array.new(3){0}
wP = WeaponItem.new("M16A1", 5, 15)
vA.push(wP)
print vA
```

Thank you

Comment: When you call `puts`, you are implicitly calling the `to_s` method of the object.  By default it prints the instance's address. Steffen's answer will do the trick for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just override the `to_s` method like this:

```
def to_s
  wName
end
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, good to know the casts can be overloaded.

Answer (score 1):

```
class WeaponItem  
  attr_reader :wName  
  def initialize(wName,mPower,mxPower)    
    @wName = wName
    @mP = mPower
    @mxP = mxPower
  end

  def getStats
    puts "Weapon"
    puts "Name: #{@wName}"
    puts "Damage: #{@mP}~#{@mxP}"
  end

  def calculateDamage()
    rMAX = @mxP/@mP
    rMAX
  end 
end

vA = Array.new
wP = WeaponItem.new("M16A1", 5, 15)
vA.push(wP.wName)
print vA
#=> ["M16A1"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have an output like `["M16"]` just by using a single `puts`, I would use the `.map` method of `Array` like this:

```
namesArray = vA.map do |weapon|
  weapon.wName
end

puts namesArray
```